# Magento 1.9.2.4 - Call to a member function getId() null in Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php:835

Tags: invoice, order-email, magento1.9.2.4

When I generate my invoice and try to save I get a error,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Order/Invoice.php:835"

And my clients can't complete the order.

[image]

```
public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewInvoiceEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }
    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
    // Check if at least one recepient is found
    if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Start store emulation process
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
    }

    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    if ($notifyCustomer) {
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
            // Add bcc to customer email
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
    }

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
    if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    // ERROR LINE BELOW
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $order,
            'invoice'      => $this,
            'comment'      => $comment,
            'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();
    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: can you share Invoice.php file code?

Comment: @Pedro Albuquerque, Please mention the Magento shop version

Comment: @Sankar_k My Magento shop version is 1.9.2.4

Comment: Ok, share the issue occur file (Invoice.php)

Comment: @Sankar_k I just checked the code of my Invoice.php and the source code of Magento 1.9.2.4 Invoice.php and they're the same.

Comment: @Sankar_k Just  added the code of my function

Comment: you did any code for sending mail is magento??

Answer (score 0):

Order object doesnt exist at time of calling function (this usually happens if function is called multiple times, e.g. by a magento event hook)

Try adding `if (!$order) { return $this; }` as below;

```
public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();

    if (!$order) { return $this; }

    $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewInvoiceEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }
    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
    // Check if at least one recepient is found
    if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Start store emulation process
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
    }

    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    if ($notifyCustomer) {
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
            // Add bcc to customer email
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
    }

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
    if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    // ERROR LINE BELOW
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));Salescast 
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $order,
            'invoice'      => $this,
            'comment'      => $comment,
            'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();
    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```